# If no values found using joins then update as values as 'Exclude'

Tags: triggers, left-join, auto-update

I wrote a trigger, where after loading the data from SSIS package, it will update the two columns based on join using ID:

Create trigger Update_CRM
on CRM
After Insert
as
begin
declare @date date
set @date =
(
SELECT MAX(CAST([Entry Date] AS DATE))
FROM CRM
)
update CRM
set CRM.[Name] = TADC.[Name],
CRM.[Group] = TADC.[Group]
from CRM CRM
left join History TADC
ON CRM.ID = TADC.ID
AND cast(CRM.[Entry Date] as Date) = TADC.[Date]
where CAST(CRM.[Entry Date] as date) = @date AND CRM.[ECC Group] is null
END

Above trigger works well. But since its a join, if no value is found, the cell values are left NULL.

Is there a way to write statement inside the trigger, if no value found in joined table, then update cell values as 'Exclude'?

Thank You